# Select/Highlight/Copy lines from a PDF in iOS using CG/Quartz

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, core-graphics, quartz-core

I've searched many sites, and found several links which explains to implement pdf reading/rendering and annotating using javascript on a webview.

I want to highlight text in a pdf just like the way its done in desktop and copy the text and send as sms/email,by a cut/copy/paste like callout which happens in textviews. Is there any link or sources to do the same way for copying text in a pdf document through the app ?

Help is appreciated..!

Comment: I am looking for a much cheaper solution €900+ is not in my budget. :P is there any free or open source codes which help out in this ?

Comment: Not aware of any - and I really searched for it. You might find some GPL code like http://poppler.freedesktop.org, but it's not prepared to work on iOS, and even if it were you couldn't use it because of the GPL. It took me the better part of a year to implement my own solution, and I work fast. You're underestimating the complexity of this problem. It's a PITA.